# Swift - Wait until a Function is Completed

Tags: ios, function, swift, xcode6

I have a application that requires a person to login for them to gain access. To do this i created a API to retrieve and store data from a database. For example, i created one to check and see if the username and password inputed is correct. The only problem though, is that the function that i use to retrieve the data is slow. It does not return the data in time for the checking system, to see if the username and password is correct.

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

var statusCode = Int()
var returnedName = String()

@IBOutlet var usernameField: UITextField
@IBOutlet var passwordField: UITextField

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

    @IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var invalidLoginAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid Username/Password", message: "Please input a correct Username or Password", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss")

    var noInfoLoginAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid Username/Password", message: "Please input a Username and Password to Proceed", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss")

    usernameField.resignFirstResponder()
    passwordField.resignFirstResponder()

    if usernameField.text != "" && passwordField.text != "" {
        login(usernameField.text.lowercaseString, password: passwordField.text.lowercaseString)
        sleep(2)
        if statusCode == 300 {
            println("Login Success")
            let MainView = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainView") as MainViewController
            self.presentViewController(MainView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            invalidLoginAlert.show()
            println("Login Failed")
        }
    }
    else {
        noInfoLoginAlert.show()
        println("Cannot Login, Invalid Information")
    }
}
```

As you see above, i have to use the sleep() function in order to slow down the function. This does not work always, because the connection is slower in different places (may take longer than 2 seconds to load) EX - 3G and LTE or slow WiFi.

The function Login(username: string, password: string), returns a code determining if the username and password is correct. If they are both correct, it will return the code 300, if not it will return 400.

Is there a way that i could could create a didFinishLoading() function, returning a bool, to check and see if the information from the login() function is loaded? this way it will not matter if their connection is slow.

Blake

**EDIT**: Here is my Networking Code:

```
func login(username: String, password: String){

    // Now escape anything else that isn't URL-friendly
    var usernameID = username.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var passwordID = password.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    var urlPath = "http://www.example.com"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary

        var name: String? = jsonResult["data"] as String?;
        var code: Int = jsonResult["status"] as Int;

        self.statusCode = code
        println(self.statusCode)
        })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Why not disable user interactions instead until the response returns?

Comment: You shouldn't use "sleep" for this. You should set up your long running calls to use either callback blocks or delegates so that you can perform the check only after the call has completed. What library or functions are you using to make your network calls?

Comment: i have a function called login() that retrieves JSON data from a database, Parses it, and then returns a Code saying if the username and password was correct or not

Comment: How are you making the network calls to the database? The library you are using to make that call should have a callback method that only calls back to your viewcontroller once the call has completed. Post your networking code.

Answer (score 1):

In your completion handler - where you are computing `jsonResult` - that is where you should notify your view controller that username and password have or have not been received.